# STM32 MBED stop mode - timer not working after wakeup

Tags: stm32, mbed, wakeup

I'm using MBED on STM32F437 MCU (my own target) and trying to properly reach STOP mode. This MCU doesn't have LPTIM (low power timer) so I'm trying to configure RTC (or WKUP pin PA0) to wakeup MCU a few seconds after STOP. So far so good. But there is problem after wakeup. MCU is running, serial printf is working, but MBED Ticker and Timer are not running as expected. Here's the deal - Ticker doesn't call attached interrupt and Timer probably overflows after wakeup.

```c
// mcu start

Timer t;
t.start();

Thread::wait(10000); // sleep is enabled 10 seconds after MCU is powered ON

-> t = 10002

// wakeup timer for 10 seconds configured
// stop mode enabled

// this happens after wakeup

-> t = 4294783
-> t = 4295784
-> t = 4296785
-> t = 4297786
-> t = 4298787
```

For wakeup i'm using this library 
https://os.mbed.com/users/Sissors/code/WakeUp/

And in Stop routine, there is code like

```c
 /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* Allow access to Backup */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();

  /* Disable all used wakeup sources: Pin1(PA.0) */
  HAL_PWR_DisableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);

  /* Clear all related wakeup flags */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

  /* Re-enable all used wakeup sources: Pin1(PA.0) */
  HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1);

  /* FLASH Deep Power Down Mode enabled */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableFlashPowerDown();

  /* Enter Stop Mode */
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);

  /* Configures system clock after wake-up from STOP: enable HSE, PLL and select
  PLL as system clock source (HSE and PLL are disabled in STOP mode) */
  SetSysClock();
```

and this is how my clock init (SetSysClock) looks like. It's called both after MCU start and MCU wakeup.

```c
/******************************************************************************/
/*            PLL (clocked by HSE) used as System clock source                */
/******************************************************************************/

uint8_t SetSysClock_PLL_HSE(uint8_t bypass)
{

    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is
       clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value
       regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet. */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    // Enable HSE oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType      = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    if (bypass == 0) {
        RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState          = RCC_HSE_ON; // External 8 MHz xtal on OSC_IN/OSC_OUT
    } else {
        RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState          = RCC_HSE_BYPASS; // External 8 MHz clock on OSC_IN
    }

    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState            = RCC_HSI_OFF;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
#if (CLOCK_SOURCE_USB)
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
#else
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
#endif
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2; // 180 MHz or 168 MHz if CLOCK_SOURCE_USB defined
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        return 0; // FAIL
    }

    // Activate the OverDrive to reach the 180 MHz Frequency
    if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK) {
        return 0; // FAIL
    }

    // Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1; // 180 or 168 MHz
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;  //  45 or  42 MHz
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;  //  90 or  84 MHz
    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK) {
        return 0; // FAIL
    }

    // HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO2, RCC_MCO2SOURCE_SYSCLK, RCC_MCODIV_3);

    return 1;
}
#endif
```